# Javascript Export a function in a function to a function in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, import, export

I have a problem with how to export a function inside a function to another function in another file. I am using React as my framework.

The code below doesn't work and I have tried several ways to solve it but nothing is working.

In **File1** I have several functions, where all of them are supposed to be returned in a View except for the signOut() function. Thus, I want to export my signOut() function and use it in another file. My function in File1 looks like:

```
function Login() {

     function signIn(){
              }

     function signUp(){
              }
        
     function signOut(){
              }
 
  return signOut, h(LoginView, {
        signIn,
        signUp    
    })

export default Login
```

In **File2** I want to use my SignOut in MenubarView.

```
import Login from './login.js'

function Menubar({}) {

    return h(MenubarView, { 
        signOut: Login.signOut()                 
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your Login function, that returns the object with other functions.

```
import Login from './login.js'

function Menubar({}) {

    return h(MenubarView, { 
        signOut: Login().signOut()                 
    });
  }
```

And you nee dto fix the return to return object:

```
function Login() {

     function signIn(){
              }

     function signUp(){
              }
        
     function signOut(){
              }
 
  return {signOut, somethingElse: h(LoginView, {
        signIn,
        signUp    
    })}

export default Login
```

To work without Login() call, you would need to add those functions to the Login function object itself.

```
function signIn(){}

function signUp(){}
        
function signOut(){}

function Login() {
  return h(LoginView, {
        this.signIn,
        this.signUp    
    })}

login.signOut = signOut;
login.signIn = signIn;
login.signUp = signUp;

export default Login
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! But I get an error message saying "TypeError: Object(...)(...).signOut is not a function"

Comment: I think you are returning something wrong still. Try

      return {signOut};

Comment: Thanks! I will try this!

Comment: Hi again! I got the error: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {signOut, somethingElse}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." I don't know how to fix that. Do I need to use SomethingElse somewhere?

Comment: What is the component you are trying to render with react? What you have above is a service or a function, not a react component.

Comment: This is the code:      
  function signOut(){ 
        setPromise(auth.signOut());
        console.log("logged out");
    }

Comment: I guess the component is a promise?